# Resizing form Window makes Form Disappear

Tags: vb.net

Okay, to give you the bigger picture here; I've got a listview that displays records from a database, I want to change the size of both the listbox and the form window relative with the amount of rows the listview contains. Simple.

Here's my code that seams to make the form disappear - note the program still runs with an icon, but no visible form at all.

`frmMain` is the form Window that contains the listview - It's height is 228.

`lvRec` is the listview - It's height is 85.

This code is stored in a file and is called when required by the form,

```
Public Sub Resizer() 



'Count records/rows with data
       Dim i As Integer
                i = frmMain.lvRec.Items.Count

'Set window Size
     If i = 3 Then
        If frmMain.Height < 247 Then
            Do Until frmMain.Height = 247
                frmMain.Height = +1
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Loop
            Do Until frmMain.lvRec.Height = 104
                frmMain.Height = +1
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Loop
        ElseIf frmMain.Height > 247 Then
            Do Until frmMain.Height = 247
                frmMain.Height = -1
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Loop
            Do Until frmMain.lvRec.Height = 104
                frmMain.lvRec.Height = -1
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Loop
        End If
```

Their are currently 3 rows in the listview, but this code makes the form disappear even though I've stated it to expand247

Comment: Use Jing to record a video and link it from here - it's freeware. Not quite clear what you mean.

Comment: This is what your debugger is for.  Set a breakpoint on `If i = 3 Then` and step through your code line-by-line.  Examine the `frmMain.Height` and `frmMain.lvRec.Height` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your current code:

```
Do Until frmMain.Height = 247
                frmMain.Height = +1
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Loop
```

Can `frmMain.Height` ever become greater than or equal to 247 if you are always setting it to `+1` ?

Comment: Hi, I'm under the impression that '+1' should increment the current form size by 1 each time it's looped...

Comment: Your impression is incorrect.  `+1` is the same as `1`.  Perhaps you meant `frmMain.Height = frmMain.Height + 1`, or `frmMain.Height += 1`

Comment: Yes, just discovered it's '+=1', I've updated my code and I seem to have a similar issue to before, I'll update this when I work out what's goin on now :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your code is getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Following through your example...

Assume `i = 3`...

```
 If i = 3 Then
    If frmMain.Height < 247 Then
        ' Most likely > 247 as that's a very small height. Let's skip on for now...
    ElseIf frmMain.Height > 247 Then
        'Else would suffice - not need for ElseIf as it ignores the case  frmMain.Height = 247
        Do Until frmMain.Height = 247
            'Shrink form height (very slowly - we're talking pixels here)
            frmMain.Height = -1 'Not correct as discussed in the other answer and below
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Loop
        Do Until frmMain.lvRec.Height = 104
            ' Who says frmMain.lvRec.Height is > 104? It may well be less in which case this loop will never end. See note below.
            frmMain.lvRec.Height = -1
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Loop
    End If
```

In general, try to use exact values in logic conditions only when you're *certain* you'll hit them every time.

Imagine a scenario where the `frmMain.lvRec.Height` started at `103`... It will decrement by `1` forever, meaning the main UI thread will be locked up and the form will never redraw.

A better (but still imperfect) example would be...

```
While frmMain.lvRec.Height <> 104
    If frmMain.lvRec.Height > 104
        frmMain.lvRec.Height -= 1 'Same as  frmMain.lvRec.Height = frmMain.lvRec.Height -1
    Else
        frmMain.lvRec.Height += 1 'vice-versa
    End If
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
End While
```

Ideally, you want the transition in size to take a fixed length of time. Let's say it should last 2 seconds (2,000 ms) in 100ms steps = 20 steps...

```
Dim Current = frmMain.lvRec.Height
Dim Desired = 104
For i = 1 to 20 '1 to 20 since we're aiming for exactly 20 steps. Normally a for would start at 0 but in this case that would cause 21 steps
    Dim Pos = Desired * (i/20) + Current * ((20-i)/20)
    frmMain.lvRec.Height = Pos
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
End While
```

What we're doing here is creating a very simplistic linear 'easing'. Effectively taking a percentage of the old value and a percentage of the new which changes over time (as `i` increases)

Example... Current value = `200`, Desired value = `100` in 20 steps (intermediate values are shown in [] to make it more comprehensible)...

```
SizeThisLoop = Desired * (i/20) + Current * ((20-i)/20)

100 * (01/20) [=05] + 200 * (19/20) [=190] = 195
100 * (02/20) [=10] + 200 * (18/20) [=180] = 190
...
100 * (05/20) [=25] + 200 * (15/20) [=150] = 175
...
100 * (20/20) [=100] + 200 * (0/20) [=000] = 100
```

This gives you a nice, linear transition.

It's worth noting that windows forms (aka WinForms) are particularly bad at this sort of thing. Quite often the user interface won't update if the main (UI) thread is in use. There are ways around this using `DoEvents` but they're hacks at best - so unless you implement some form of background threading, the UI will most likely lock up until you've finished with your loop (this is why your form disappeared - it was resizing forever and didn't get a chance to redraw).

There are a couple of alternatives. WPF is designed with nice effects like this in mind but behaves in a completely different fashion and couldn't be written in this way.

Failing that, the use of a background thread can help - the background thread resizes over time and tells the foreground thread to resize the window when it can.

Something like...

```
Public Sub Resizer()
    'Set up a background thread to do the resizing
    Dim T As New Threading.Thread(Sub() ResizeWorker())
    T.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub ResizeWorker()
    'The background thread. Takes approx 2 seconds to complete
    Dim Current = frmMain.lvRec.Height
    Dim Desired = 104
    For i = 1 to 20 '1 to 20 since we're aiming for exactly 20 steps. Normally a for would start at 0 but in this case that would cause 21 steps
        Dim Pos = Desired * (i/20) + Current * ((20-i)/20)
        UIResize(Cint(Pos)) 'Do a resize
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    End While
End Sub


Private Sub UIResize(NewSize As Integer)
    'Only the UI thread is allowed to update controls. Check if we're allowed to do so? (Can we make a change without invoking another thread?)
    If Me.InvokeRequired
        'This code isn't being executed on the UI thread. Ask the UI thread to run this method with the same parameters when it when it can
        Me.Invoke(Sub() UIResize(NewSize))
    Else
        'We're now running on the UI thread... Resize at will!
        Me.lvRec.Height = NewSize
    End IF
End Sub
```